# Does the quotient of a variety with log terminal singularities also have log terminal singularities?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Boutot's theorem says that if $X$ is a variety over a field of characteristic 0 with rational singularities, and if $G$ is a reductive group acting on $X$, then the quotient $X/G$ has rational singularities as well.

Is it known whether an analog of this result is true for log terminal singularities?

Namely suppose $X$ is a variety over a field of characteristic 0 with log terminal singularities and an action of a reductive group $G$. Then must $X/G$ also have log terminal singularities?

Comment: No, the singularity $\{xy-zw=0\}\subset \mathbb{A}^4$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{A}^4$ by a torus, but its canonical divisor is not $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier, so is not log terminal.

Comment: @JoaquínMoraga I do not understand : this is a hypersurface singularity, and as such it is Gorenstein, so the canonical divisor is actually Cartier!

Comment: @OlivierBenoist Oops. I meant to quotient the hypersurface by a finite group afterwards. It seems I can't edit anymore. Anyways, any 3-fold toric singularity which is not $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein will make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I can give you a definite answer. In general, the quotient of a klt singularity by a reductive group is not klt, because for instance, the canonical divisor of the quotient may not be $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier.

However, one can define a broader notion: klt type. A singularity $(X;x)$ is said to be of klt type if there exists a boundary $B$ through $x$ for which $(X,B;x)$ is klt.
Then, one gets the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $X$ be an affine variety with klt type singularities over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $G$ be a reductive group acting on $X$. Then $X/\!/G$ is of klt type again.

The previous is Theorem 1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.02812.
I should also mention that the klt type property is an etale property, i.e., if you can check it in an etale cover of $X$ then it holds for $X$. This is Proposition 4.1. in https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.02812.
Furthermore, the klt type condition